# Does Enigmail defaultly check keyservers upon receiving signed emails?

Tags: thunderbird, gnupg, enigmail

How does Enigmail acquire the public key for someone who sends you an encrypted email? Do you have to import it yourself or does it get the key from a keyserver?

Answer (score 0):

The key is (usually) written into the message headers. But this (encrypted) mail does not contain *any* information on the sender, if it isn't signed. Let's analyze what is contained in an OpenPGP messages.

### Decomposing an Encrypted OpenPGP Message

You can see this if you list the packets contained in an encrypted message:

```
$ echo foo | gpg --encrypt --recipient 0xa4ff2279 | gpg --list-packets
```

The output starts with the "publicly" visible, unencrypted headers, which contain the subkey the message is encrypted for:

```
:pubkey enc packet: version 3, algo 1, keyid CC73B287A4388025
    data: [4092 bits]
```

After entering the passphrase, GnuPG will also print the remaining packets:

```
:encrypted data packet:
    length: 63
    mdc_method: 2
gpg: encrypted with 4096-bit RSA key, ID A4388025, created 2014-03-26
      "Jens Erat (born 1988-01-19 in Stuttgart, Germany)"
:compressed packet: algo=2
:literal data packet:
    mode b (62), created 1402861918, name="",
    raw data: 4 bytes
```

### Decomposing a Signed OpenPGP Message

A *signed* message contains the signing (sub)key ID of the sender, see the `:signature packet` line (fourth packet).

```
$ echo foo | gpg --sign | gpg --list-packets
```

(GnuPG asks for password, for signing)

```
:compressed packet: algo=1
:onepass_sig packet: keyid 8E78E44DFB1B55E9
    version 3, sigclass 0x00, digest 2, pubkey 1, last=1
:literal data packet:
    mode b (62), created 1402862406, name="",
    raw data: 4 bytes
:signature packet: algo 1, keyid 8E78E44DFB1B55E9
    version 4, created 1402862406, md5len 0, sigclass 0x00
    digest algo 2, begin of digest 9a d2
    hashed subpkt 2 len 4 (sig created 2014-06-15)
    subpkt 16 len 8 (issuer key ID 8E78E44DFB1B55E9)
    data: [4095 bits]
```

An encrypted OpenPGP message could of course also be signed. I'm leaving composing the commands for verifying this as exercise to the interested reader.

### Obtaining the Public Keys

Using the key ID obtained from the *signed* message, one can fetch the key from the key servers. Most mail clients (plugins) will do this automatically for you:

```
$ gpg --recv-keys 0x8E78E44DFB1B55E9
gpg: requesting key FB1B55E9 from hkp server pool.sks-keyservers.net
gpg: key A4FF2279: "Jens Erat (born 1988-01-19 in Stuttgart, Germany)" not changed
gpg: Total number processed: 1
gpg:              unchanged: 1
```

If the message isn't signed, you (or your OpenPGP client) might search the key servers for the mail address of the other. Result is the same, you still cannot be sure about the validity of that key.

Answer (score 0):

So, I took a more direct route to finding out about this question.  [Enigmail](https://www.enigmail.net/home/index.php) has a nice website, and a good handbook which explains a great deal about it's operation for a casual user like me, who likes encryption but gets lost in the coding.

In section 8 of the [HTML version of the handbook](http://www.rainydayz.org/content/831-encrypting-message), Enigmail requires the use of a the recipient's public key to encrypt the message for them to read.  If you don't already have their public key, then apparently it might be able to find a public key on a keyserver.  This is covered in [section 7 of the handbook](http://www.rainydayz.org/content/76-importing-public-keys).